# django-taggit problem with Persian language

Tags: django, django-taggit

I am working with django and also I want to use `django-taggit` for tags but the problem is that for Persian language when I use `django-taggit` I cannot use Persian words because it has problems to use Persian words as slug.

What can I do? Is there any solution for this or I have to create a Tagging system by myself for Persian?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `django-taggit 1.4.0` and it is working fine.

- **In the admin:**

[image]

- **On the actual blog page:**

[image]

- **You can also use them in urls with no slug problems:**

[image]

Comment: thanks @MohammadHosseinZiyaaddini but I solved my problem by creating my own tagging system